# Building Ffmpeg library for iOS6.0 ARMv7 Processor success but compile error

Tags: ffmpeg, ios6

I'm trying to use the FFMPEG library in an XCode 4.5.1 project.
And I'm trying to build it for ARMv7.

I had already build library by use the method below (provide by Alex):

---

Here is my working Configure for cross-compiling FFmpeg on iOS 6 the arch is ARMv7

NOTE: You must have to have gas-preprocessor.pl inside /usr/local/bin/ please do not continue until you have gas-preprocessor.pl on your bin directory

Download FFmpeg 1.0 "Angel" from here

Unzip it and place it somewhere i.e. your Desktop folder

Open terminal and browse to unzipped FFmpeg folder

Copy and paste the following command, (be patient will take a while)

```
./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk' --enable-pic --enable-decoder=rawvideo --disable-asm
```

Now type the following command on terminal `make` (wait a little more)

Once it has finished now type on terminal `sudo make install` (wait again)

Go to `/usr/local/lib` to find your freshly baked armv7 libs

Enjoy!

Alex

---

But when i put the library into `iFrameExtractor` then compile it, then i get an error

> /ffmpeg/libavcodec/4xm.d:1: syntax error near "xm"

my Compilation environment is

xcode 4.5.1 and ffmpeg 1.0

platform: Mac OS X 10.7.5

can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 1):

Where are you seeing this message in the log?

```
ffmpeg/libavcodec/4xm.d:1: syntax error near "xm"
```

What messages are before and after this?

Is this the whole message?

If you don't mind using the FFmpeg release prior to 1.0, not much difference really then you can use our framework for FFmpeg: https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/iFrameExtractor

If you still want to build 1.0 then please give us more of the error to go by. The error message you posted does not give enough detail to act on.

Answer (score 0):

For that you are using the Gcc compiler. Gcc compiler will be preferable to use when you are building the libraries for iPhoneSimulator. But right now you are trying to build the libraries for iPhoneOS, So it means your hardware platform will change which will be (armv6 or armv7 or armv7s). For that you need to use gcc cross compiler of apple for armv processor.

e.g: arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2
or try once with : llvm-gcc   also.

I hope this can help someone.